# Flink Temp Jar Upload Directory Deleted

Tags: hadoop, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have recently been unable to upload any jars to my Flink cluster, running under YARN on AWS EMR. There has been a long-running streaming application running for 26 days. It seems like the temp directory has been deleted, but I really don't think that I deleted it.

From the `jobmanager.log`:

```
2019-02-12 22:02:05,156 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarListHandler   - Jar upload dir /tmp/flink-web-94fee1e8-35b9-409f-be97-d86c0f021459/flink-web-upload does not exist, or had been deleted externally. Previously uploaded jars are no longer available.
```

The instance has plenty of space for storing the jar.

Here is the YARN app status:

```
Application-Id : application_1547758510009_0001
Application-Name : Flink session cluster
Application-Type : Apache Flink
User : hadoop
Queue : default
Application Priority : 0
Start-Time : 1547758629234
Finish-Time : 0
Progress : 100%
State : RUNNING
Final-State : UNDEFINED
Tracking-URL : http://ip-cp1.ec2.internal:39975
RPC Port : 39975
AM Host : ip-cp1.ec2.internal
Aggregate Resource Allocation : 43765538005 MB-seconds, 4500338 vcore-seconds
Aggregate Resource Preempted : 0 MB-seconds, 0 vcore-seconds
Log Aggregation Status : NOT_START
Diagnostics : 
Unmanaged Application : false
Application Node Label Expression : <Not set>
AM container Node Label Expression : <DEFAULT_PARTITION>
```

I have not set either `jobmanager.web.upload.dir` nor `jobmanager.web.tmpdir`. After recreating that directory, I am able to upload into it through cURL (and verify that the file arrives) but then subsequently listing the jars shows nothing.

Has anyone seen this before? And also, how can I now correctly recreate the necessary upload directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Linux distributions periodically clean up the temp directory (`/tmp`), i.e., not only on a restart.

You should configure Flink to use a non-temp directory to store the JARs.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify, I would do this with the `jobmanager.web.upload.dir` setting, even with YARN?